# Custom Bundle with Symfony 6.2

Tags: symfony6

I'm trying to create a Bundle to share some services and utility classes between my different projects.
I already did this while using Symfony 5.4. But now I want to migrate to **PHP 8.1** using **Symfony 6.2**.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but my web projects just don't see the services I'm creating in my Bundle.

Step by step:

1. I created my web project that will use the Bundle with:

`symfony new my-webapp --version="6.2.*" --webapp`

2. I created the project for the Bundle using composer.json like this:

```
{
    "name": "carlospauluk/my-bundle",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/http-kernel": "6.2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyBundleNamespace\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyBundleNamespace\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    }
}
```

Inside config/services.yaml, I changed it to:

```
parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    MyBundleNamespace\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
```

So I created my service in src/Service:

```
<?php

namespace MyBundleNamespace\Service;

class NumberGeneratorService
{

    public function generate(int $max) {
        return random_int(0, $max);
    }

}
```

Apparently my service is correctly configured in the Bundle, right?
After that, in my my-webapp, in composer.json I added the local repository of my my-bundle folder:

```
,
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../my-bundle"
    }
]
```

and then...

`composer require "carlospauluk/my-bundle @dev"`

Okay, I was hoping that everything was already working, and that my NumberGeneratorService service was already available in my-webapp. But not. When I run:

`php bin/console debug:container MyBundleNamespace`

It returns:

`No services found that match "MyBundleNamespace".`

What could be missing?

When I set up my bundles in my projects using Symfony 5.4, I don't remember doing anything much different than this.

Could you help me please?

Both codes are here:

https://github.com/carlospauluk/my-bundle

https://github.com/carlospauluk/my-webapp

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after almost 3 days of trying, I figured out how it should be done.

I needed to implement the loadExtension method inside the /src/MyBundle.php

```
<?php

namespace MyBundleNamespace;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator\ContainerConfigurator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\AbstractBundle;

class MyBundle extends AbstractBundle
{

    public function loadExtension(array $config, ContainerConfigurator $container, ContainerBuilder $builder): void
    {
        $container->import(__DIR__ . '/Resources/config/services.xml');
    }

}
```

And also had to create the /src/Resources/config/services.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services
         http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

     <services>

         <service id="my_bundle_namespace.service.number_generator_service"
                  class="MyBundleNamespace\Service\NumberGeneratorService">
         </service>
         <service id="MyBundleNamespace\Service\NumberGeneratorService" public="true"
                  alias="my_bundle_namespace.service.number_generator_service"/>


     </services>
</container>
```

Without this, it doesn't work.

The Symfony Framework is excellent, but it's unfortunate that its documentation is so weak and confusing in places.

For example, at https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html about the they say "This empty class is the only piece you need to create the new bundle.", which we clearly see is not true. Without implementing the loadExtension method we cannot access any services inside the bundle. If they said that clearly, it would be much easier.
Symfony's documentation is too compreehnsive, despite being very shalow at some points.

Comment: I also stumbled on this part, you need to look further into the document "How to Create Friendly Configuration for a Bundle" to find this part: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html#using-the-abstractbundle-class.
And If your Bundle class extends from `AbstractBundle` or `Bundle`, it requires different configuration.